# Strftime Displaying Incorrect Time

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is get the correct time of the user browsing my website and add 10 minutes to the current time. Here is hte code I have:

```
<?php
$now = time();
$closetime = $now+600;
echo strftime("%A %b %e %I:%M%p %Z",$closetime) . "\n";
?>
```

Everything works as I intended, the only issue that the timezone is off.  I'm currently on the eastcoast so its 12:55 here, but the above code would output: `Monday Oct  7 12:05PM CDT` which is 1 hour behind what I want.

How do I make this appear correctly for the user so no matter what country or timezone it will always display 10 minutes from the current time?

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: Do you want to display in the user's timezone? PHP can't get that directly, you need help from Javascript.

Comment: @AmalMurali will that display in the users timezone?

Comment: @Barmar yes thats what I'm trying to do.. how do I do that with javascript?

Comment: @JoeBobby: Nope, you'll have to use [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/) for that (what Barmar said above).

Comment: See the answer from Westy92 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498128/guessing-users-timezone-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Check the timezone you are using with `ini_get('date.timezone')`. If isn't the right timezone search for `date.timezone` in your php.ini file and edit the value for one of the [supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) values that PHP have.

`date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"`

If you don't have access to the php.ini file you can overwrite that value with [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function at the begining of your app evertytime it is executed.